# Receive events for additional mouse buttons in a WindowProc

Tags: windows, input, mouseevent

There are some mouses that have exotic buttons like side buttons, lateral wheel pulling... these events can usually be received with the DirectInput API and the [`DIMOUSESTATE2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.dimousestate2%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct.

Is there a way to get these event with a normal `WindowProc` message loop, along with `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and such?